# Ubiquitous way to get the root directory an application is running in via C#

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5

My application requires that I have access to the file system. Regardless if the code runs on a web server or a console app, how can I get the root directory the application is running in. Something like C:\TheApplication...

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easiest is probably:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

Hope this helps,

-Oisin

Comment: Ahhhhh...I have my idiot hat on today ;) Totally forgot about that!

Comment: Out of curiosity, I wonder what is returned when the executing assembly is in the Global Assembly Cache?

Comment: @jdk, just a guess, but wouldn't this return the calling EXE, rather than the assembly placing the reflection call?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
String path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

You can read more about the two classes here:

- [Assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly_members.aspx) class
- [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) class

Answer (score 1):

I just tested out a very basic way to do this that works in both asp.net and within a windows service.

```
var binariesPath = string.IsNullOrEmpty(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.RelativeSearchPath) 
                    ? AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory // Windows Service
                    : AppDomain.CurrentDomain.RelativeSearchPath; // Asp.net
```

Answer (score 0):

Even easier:

```
string myPath = Application.ExecutablePath;
```

For winforms application, this is always set.

Comment: I'm not a C# programmer, and I haven't looked up the docs, but just from the name of that I would expect it to return the path to the executable file, rather than the current working directory.  I suspect the OP wants the working directory.