# Ubiquitous way to get the file system root of a .NET WEB application

Tags: c#, .net, webforms

Similar to [Ubiquitous way to get the root directory an application is running in via C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652001/ubiquitous-way-to-get-the-root-directory-an-application-is-running-in-via-c), but that question seems to be related to Win Forms. How would the same be done for Web Forms?

I was using...

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~")
```

This works great for handling HTTP requests but seems not to work if a scheduler like [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) invokes a job (the problem I am having). The `HttpContext.Current` is null in that scenario since an actual HTTP request is not made.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the [`HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.appdomainapppath.aspx) property, and perhaps the [`VirtualPathUtility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.virtualpathutility.aspx) class.

Comment: HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath worked for returning the web application root. This seems to be the more straight forward property for obtaining root.

Answer (score 5):

Try the [`System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.mappath.aspx) method.  AFAIK it's not dependent on HttpContext so you should be able to use it from a background thread.

Comment: +1 System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~") worked for returning the web application root.

Answer (score 0):

Use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`. This corresponds to `AppDomainSetup.ApplicationBase` which states that it is 'The name of the application base directory.'

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.applicationbase.aspx